# Does terraform support ssh password protected key?

Tags: ssh-keys, terraform

I'm trying to use this config in here:

```
connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "root"
    agent = true
    private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
}
```

I've got error:

```
password protected keys are not supported. Please decrypt the key prior to use.
```

I've also tried to remove `private_key` parameter. It just have to read keys from ssh-agent, but it doesn't work. 
Terraform version is `0.9.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Solved. Problem was that ssh_keys fingerprints are not specified, so vm been created without any ssh key assigned. But error itself is very misleading.

So just add this:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "mydroplet" {
   ssh_keys = [
      "<fingerprint can be found in digital ocean ssh keys tab>"
   ]
}
```

Comment: It *is* true that password-protected keys are not supported, so removing the `private_key` argument is part of the solution since you (presumably) wanted to use the key installed in your SSH agent here, which you specified with `agent = true`. Unfortunately SSH setup across all providers is rather complex, so there are lots of tricky ways things can go wrong and it's hard for Terraform to give good error messages for all the different situations. :(